# Does the probability distribution of cosine transformation of uniformly distributed R.V. depend on phase shift of the cosine function?

Tags: noise, random

Suppose, x is uniformly distributed over [0,2π], and y = cos(x + ∆), will the probability distribution function of y depend on ∆?

Is my solution to find out the Probability Distribution function of Y, correct?

Image of the solution: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELoO0.jpg

Answer (score 1):

cos(*x*) is periodic. Its period is 2π. Then it doesn't matter what **∆** is, the probability distribution will always be the same as the probability distribution of cos(*x*) over a full cycle (e.g. for *x* in [0, 2π]).

**∆** would have mattered if **x** wasn't uniformly distributed, or if it wasn't distributed over a 2π range (or an integer multiple of 2π for that matter).

To me this is just obvious, I don't know if you need to prove it more rigorously though.